# Angular2 take table data in array

Tags: angular, typescript

[Bootstrap table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6npb.png)

take table data in array using typescript.

Comment: when i submit form i will get array of particular table.

Comment: Welcome to SO Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn some details about the expected format of questions on the site

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: i have simple registration form. Qualification details show in table. one student can have many qualification. when i click on submit form i will get other fields value i want also qualification details array when i submit.. Angular2 and typescript

Answer (score 0):

You should be using formControls + formGroup. Just simply retrieve values from the formGroup/Controls on submit of the form. Submit should call a function, in your component handle that function and just retrieve values from the formGroup/formControls.